# How do I remove manually installed packages?

Tags: package-management, uninstall, openldap

I have followed this tutorial http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/quickstart.html
on installing OpenLDAP, but now I want to remove it.

I'm not sure which command should I use for that. Can somebody point me in right direction?

Cheers

Answer (score 9):

If the makefile is correctly written, you should be able to cd back into the directory where you ran `./configure` and `make` and this time run `make uninstall`

You should also look at installing checkinstall to use in these situations - it will allow you to build from source, but have the packages tracked by apt.

`sudo apt-get install checkinstall` and then `man checkinstall`